# Exception Handling Errors

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors

I'm working on a program based on 2 classes that convert military time while also using exception handling. I am trouble with 3 compiler errors. The first 2 are in the Time class, it says it cannot find the symbol for the variable time. The 3rd error has to do with how I am trying to display my results in the TimeConverterTest class, it says it cannot find the militaryTime variable.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Time
{

    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private boolean afternoon;
    String  am_pm;

    public Time(String time)
    {

    }

    public String convertToMilitary(String militaryTime)
    {
      try{
            if (time == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ("No time was entered");

            }
            else if (time > 5)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Less than 5 characters were entered");
            }
            else
            {
                 if ( militaryTime.charAt(2) != ':' )
                {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The third character was not a colon");
                 }
                 else if ( !Character.isDigit( militaryTime.charAt( 0 ) ) )
                {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The first character was not passed as a digit");
                 }
                else if ( !Character.isDigit( militaryTime.charAt( 1 ) ) )
                {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The second character was not passed as a digit");
                 }
                else if ( !Character.isDigit( militaryTime.charAt( 2 ) )  )
                {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The fourth character was not passed as a digit");
                 }
                else if ( !Character.isDigit( militaryTime.charAt( 4 ) ) )
                {
                     throw new IllegalArgumentException ("The fifth character was not passed as a digit");
                 }
                else
                {

                    hours = Integer.parseInt(militaryTime.substring( 0,2 ));
                    minutes = Integer.parseInt( militaryTime.substring( 3,5 ));

                     if( hours > 23)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Hours passed were greater than 23");
                     }
                    else if( minutes > 59)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Minutes passed were greater than 59");
                     }
                     else if (hours > 12)
                    {
                        afternoon = false;
                    }
                     else if (hours == 0)
                    {
                        hours = 12;

                    }
                     else if (hours == 12)
                    {
                        afternoon = true;

                    }
                     else
                    {
                        System.out.println(hours + ":" + minutes );
                    }

                        }

                   }    
        }
       catch (IllegalArgumentException exception)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    exception.getMessage(),
                    "Invalid Argument", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }

      String  am_pm = hours + ":" + minutes;

        return "\n\n" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + am_pm + "\n\n";
    }

}
```

and the TimeConverterTest is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TimeConverterTest {

    public static final String[] menuChoice = {"Convert Military Time to Standard",
            "Convert Standard Time to Military",
            "Exit the System"};

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        while(true){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("TIME CONVERSION MACHINE");
            String option = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                    "What do you want to do?",
                    "Time Conversion Machine",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    menuChoice,
                    menuChoice[0]);

            int choice = Arrays.asList(menuChoice).indexOf(option) + 1;

            System.out.print(choice);


            Scanner input;

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:


                    input = new Scanner(System.in);

                    // Prompt user to enter Military time with message "Please enter Military Time:"
                    //CODE to make it work

                    System.out.printf("Please enter Military Time: ");

                    // Create militaryTime variable to accept input
                    //CODE to make it work;

                    String time;
                    time = input.nextLine();
                    // Create new 'timeToConvert' object using militaryTime
                    //CODE to make it work

                    Time timeToConvert = new Time( time);  


                    // Using your newly created object call the necessary method to convert the time and
                    // Display your results


                    //Display your results
                    String results =  timeToConvert.convertToMilitary(militaryTime);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,results);

                    break;

                case 2:


                case 3:

                    System.exit(0);

            }

        }
    }

}// end of class TimeConverterTest
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get `cannot be resolved to a variable` compile error if the variable is not declared

In `Time` class

```
public String convertToMilitary(String militaryTime) {
    try {
        if (militaryTime == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No time was entered");

        } else if (militaryTime.length() < 5) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Less than 5 characters were entered");
```

`TimeConverterClass`

```
        String results = timeToConvert.convertToMilitary(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare time variable as

```
String  time;

    public Time(String time)
    {
         this.time = time;
    }
```

in Time class so that it could be used and as you are getting String time as in put at

```
// Create militaryTime variable to accept input
//CODE to make it work;

 String time;
 time = input.nextLine();
```

then pass that variable as

```
 //Display your results
  String results =  timeToConvert.convertToMilitary(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in passing the `time` variable into the `Time` class constructor, however, you never actually transferred the variable into the class. Below i declared an instance variable `time`, below `am_pm`, and inside the constructor I set it equal to the passed in `time` variable.

```
private int hours;
private int minutes;
private boolean afternoon;
String  am_pm;
String time;

public Time(String time)
{
    this.time = time;
}
```

You seem to be confused about method parameters and method return value. You need to either pass the time variable inside the constructor and use it within the class, or just pass it directly to `convertToMilitary`, without going thru the constructor.

The return value of `convertToMilitary` is your intended military time, and the *parameter* should be just the regular time value. Keeping that in mind, your code should look like this.

```
String time;
time = input.nextLine();
// Create new 'timeToConvert' object using militaryTime
//CODE to make it work

Time timeToConvert = new Time( time);  
// Using your newly created object call the necessary method to convert the     time and
// Display your results

//Display your results
String militaryTime =  timeToConvert.convertToMilitary(time);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,militaryTime );
```